# Multiple classes in Codeigniter

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter, class

I want to create an array of objects, so what I did was to create a library but I can't figure out how to actually dynamically create instances of it in a loop and store each instance in an array.
Can anyone tell me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design, loading a CodeIgniter library can only be done once. Subsequent attempts to load the same library are ignored. You can (in a way) get around this by telling CI to instantiate the class with a different name every time you load another copy of the library (see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693260/how-do-you-create-multiple-instances-of-a-library-class-in-codeigniter))

A better solution is probably to create your class yourself, instead of using CI's library loading mechanism. That way you can create and store as many copies as you need.

EDIT: I'd suggest leaving the class in the libraries directory, and just using PHP's include() to make it available to your models/controllers where needed.

As for accessing CodeIgniter from within your class, you can do it using the following code:

```
$CI =& get_instance();

$CI->load->helper('url');
$CI->load->library('session');
$CI->config->item('base_url');
```

The get_instance() function returns the CodeIgniter super object, and once it's assigned to the $CI variable, you can access any of CI's methods just like you would from within a model or controller, except using $CI instead of $this. See [this link](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html) for more information.

Comment: Great, I like this solution - however, where do I store my class, physically and how do I include it in a model or a view for example. Also I would like to use Ci's classes and libraries from with in this class, Would that be possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To create 100 objects, you just need to loop from 0 to 99, creating an object every time and storing it in the array.

```
class Foo { ... }

$fooArray = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $fooArray[] = new Foo();
}
```

I'm not sure what this question has to do with CodeIgniter. Is there more you're not mentioning?

Comment: I already know how to create an object in php.
However, as far as I know, you don't just create classes in CI but instead libraries and then load theme like so: $this->load->library('libraryName');
This line creates an instance of libraryName and stores it in a variable called libraryName. Instead of that, I would like it to return that instance so I can store it in an array.
Thanks.

Comment: From what I understand, CodeIgniter's not really object-oriented. Each library is a singleton, and multiple calls just get the same instance. This is by design, and I don't believe there's a clean way to go around it. The best way, as far as I know, would be to `require` the library file and instantiate it yourself, rather than use `$this->load->library`.